# Strategies for Crash Report and debugging After Publish

Tags: android, bug-reporting

What should be Strategies for Crash Report and debugging After Publish. I know about ACRA and Bugsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only strategy for crash report is **finding the bug** and **fixing it**. Apart from the ones you mentioned in your question **ACRA** and **Bugsense** Google play developer console  also has a dedicated **Crashes and ANRs** tab under each published application. See the pic:
[image]

Comment: That I know, But the problem with default error reporting doesn't let us know the state of phone ... Like, If there is already some app is running or it came to low memory app will crash. since heap size is different for different manufactures. In that case  it will report to play. Which is not considerable. And Bugsense and ACRA is more about Pay.